# .setFormula() and received error missing ) argument list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have `.setFormula()` and stuck on this. I think the problem is the comma (`&","`). I have researched several online forum before posting this question but no luck; perhaps someone here could help me out. I do know the rules about using the `""` and `''` that's why I have tried several formulas but still, I receive the error message:

> "Missing ) after argument list".

Your time and help is appreciated!

Original formula:

```
=arrayformula(concatenate(filter('Sheet1'!E2:E,'Sheet1'!E2:E<>"")&", "))
```

code:

```
me.getRange('B8').setFormula("=arrayformula(concatenate(filter('Sheet1'!E2:E,'Sheet1'!E2:E<>"") & ", "))");
```

Formulas I have tried but failed:

```
"=arrayformula(concatenate(filter('Sheet1'!E2:E,'Sheet1'!E2:E<>'') & ', '))");
'=arrayformula(concatenate(filter('Sheet1'!E2:E,'Sheet1'!E2:E<>'') & ', '))');
"=arrayformula(concatenate(filter('Sheet1'!E2:E,'Sheet1'!E2:E<>'') & ", "))");
'=arrayformula(concatenate(filter("Sheet1"!E2:E,"Sheet1"!E2:E<>"") & ", "))');
```

Comment: @I'-'I, My apologies, my data is supposed to grab it from another worksheet (not Sheet1). I changed the name so fast that I didn't see that. Sorry about that. I should still use the single quote 'Sheet2'!E2:E...but the comma after & " , " is not recognized.

Comment: You need single quotes, if and only if the sheet name contains spaces (like `Sheet 1`). It doesn't matter,if it is second sheet or sheet100

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your input. Your suggestion below worked for me, using the back lashes. I have tested my code and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need single quotes `'` around `Sheet1`.

Try

```
me.getRange('B8')
    .setFormula('=arrayformula(concatenate(filter(Sheet1!E2:E,Sheet1!E2:E<>"") & ", "))"');
```

If you still need it, you need to escape it with backlashes like this `\'`:

```
me.getRange('B8')
    .setFormula('=arrayformula(concatenate(filter(\'Sheet1\'!E2:E,\'Sheet1\'!E2:E<>"") & ", "))"');
```

#### Reference:

[String § Escape notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Thank you @ I'-'I. That works. I learned something new today using the backlashes.