# Auto fill new rows with formula using script editor works for one formula but not another

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the script editor in google sheets to auto-fill a formula into new rows created by an app. My problem is that this works with one formula, but another causes an error, even though both formulas work correctly if pasted into the cell itself.

All I have done is changing the formula. I am a beginner at this and have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCBtsQGtzoQ

THIS WORKS

```
function AUTOFILLLINK() {
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss3. getRange("AD2").setFormula("=(F2&G2&E2)");
  var lr3 = ss3. getLastRow();
  var filldownrange3 = ss3.getRange(2, 30, lr3-1);
  ss3. getRange("AD2").copyTo(filldownrange3);
}
```

THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK - it returns the following error:
Missing ) after argument list. (line 3, file "AUTOFILL LINKS")Dismiss

```
function AUTOFILLLINK() {
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss3.getRange("AD2").setFormula("=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)),"", (VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)))");
  var lr3 = ss3. getLastRow();
  var filldownrange3 = ss3.getRange(2, 30, lr3-1);
  ss3. getRange("AD2").copyTo(filldownrange3);
}
```

Could somebody please explain why the second variant does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.setFormula() and received error missing ) argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429442/setformula-and-received-error-missing-argument-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `""` by `''` or `\"\"`.

by writing `""` you end your string by this quote mark and reopen a new string. so you basically have two possible strings which are not concatenated so the syntax is invalid, the interpreter is waiting at the first string a `)`, that's why you get this message:

**first string**

```
"=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)),"
```

**second string**

```
", (VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)))"
```

you could do:

```
ss3.getRange("AD2").setFormula("=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false))," + ", (VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)))");
```

but one argument would be empty and you would get in your cell:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)),, (VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)))
```

so try:

```
ss3.getRange("AD2").setFormula("=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)),'', (VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)))");
```

Comment: Thank you so much JSmith =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false)),, (VLOOKUP(AK11,Links!A:E,5,false))) works a Treat as I wanted empty cells for another fomula

Comment: @JohnnyCardel could you mark as answered please.Thanks in avance

Comment: Both worked and I am trying to get my head around it could you please help with this line     ss4.getRange("AD2").setFormula("=IF((AND(OR(I8="YT DWL",I8="MGP DWL (YT + AA + BONUS)"),L8<=0,AD8<>"")), "Send Email", "Wait")");       Thanks again

Comment: @JohnnyCardel I asking you to mark as answered by clicking on the green check mark on the top left of your post. just replace all your `"` characters by `'` except for the start and end of your string this sould do something like this:  `"=IF((AND(OR(I8='YT DWL',I8='MGP DWL (YT + AA + BONUS)'),L8<=0,AD8<>'')), 'Send Email', 'Wait')"`

Comment: Sorry but it took me a while to find the green check mark as it was grey until I checked it and my brain was already on overload trying to figure my scripting out, Thanks a bunch JSmith for all your help.

Comment: @JohnnyCardel no problem glad it helped you out.