# Using Formulas in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, concatenation

So I am working in GAS (Google Apps Script) and have taken a look at the following function:

```
function myFunction(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("B5");
cell.setFormula("=SUM(B3:B4)");
}
```

I want to write a formula in GAS that concatenates two values with a Randbetween formula. When I click on a cell and type the code it gives the desired output:

> =CONCATENATE("61", RANDBETWEEN(10, 99), "@text")
>   6177@text

But when I apply the principles in GAS, I receive error message.

> Missing ) after argument list. (line 6, file "Code")

Here is the code I am using:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
cell.setFormula("=CONCATENATE("61", RANDBETWEEN(10, 99), "@text")");

}
```

Why won't this code work? How can I make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.setFormula() and received error missing ) argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429442/setformula-and-received-error-missing-argument-list)

Comment: Escape inner quotes `\"` or enclose everything in single quotes `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
  cell.setFormula('=CONCATENATE("61", RANDBETWEEN(10, 99), "@text")');
}
```

I replaced the double quotes and single quotes in the following line -
`cell.setFormula('=CONCATENATE("61", RANDBETWEEN(10, 99), "@text")');`

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Anomalous - I'm glad to hear that :) Kindly consider accepting the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer