# Google Sheets Apps Script Autofill Formula Syntax Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax-error, autofill, google-apps-script-editor

I am trying to create a script that will autofill column G with a formula that I have.

Here is my code so far:

```
function autofill() {
  // Activate sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Insert formula in first row
  ss.getRange("G2").setFormula("=IF(REGEXMATCH(E2,"No"),0,IF(REGEXMATCH(F2,"No"),1,2))");

  // Get number of last row
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();

  // Fill formula to last row
  // getRange(row number, col number, number of rows, number of cols)
  var fillDownRange = ss.getRange(2, 7, lastrow-1);
  ss.getRange("G2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```

I keep getting an error:
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (line 6, file "Code.gs")

btw line 6 is:

```
ss.getRange("G2").setFormula("=IF(REGEXMATCH(E2,"No"),0,IF(REGEXMATCH(F2,"No"),1,2))");
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.setFormula() and received error missing ) argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429442/setformula-and-received-error-missing-argument-list)

Comment: Use single quotes as delimiter or escape all double quotes between the outer double quotes. If done correctly, everything inside setValue() should be in a uniform color(Brown here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
function autofill() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange("G2").setFormula('=IF(REGEXMATCH(E2,"No"),0,IF(REGEXMATCH(F2,"No"),1,2))');
  var fillDownRange=sh.getRange(2,7,sh.getLastRow()-1);
  sh.getRange("G2").copyTo(fillDownRange);
}
```