# Google apps script error: Missing ] after element list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script which resets a page, so in the script I have a list of formulas used in the sheet that must remain there when the sheet is reset.

When I add the below formulas, and try to save the script, I get the error: 'missing ']' after element list:

// formulas that must be present and un-tampered-with to submit. Adjust if necessary

```
var sheetFormulas = 
[
["C6", "=SUM(C5-G5)"],
["I10", "=SUM(B10:H10)"],
["I12", "=SUM(B12:H12)"],
["I13", "=SUM(B13:H13)"],
["I14", "=SUM(B14:H14)"],
["I15", "=SUM(B15:H15)"],
["I16", "=SUM(B16:H16)"],
["I18", "=SUM(B18:H18)"],
["I19", "=SUM(B19:H19)"],
["K10", "=-ROUND(I10/23*20,2)"],
["K12", "=-ROUND(I12/23*20,2)"],
["K13", "=ROUND(I13/23*20,2)"],
["K14", "=I14"]
["K15", "=ROUND(I15/23*20,2)"],
["K16", "=ROUND(I16/23*20,2)"],
["K18", "=I18"],
["K19", "=I19"],
["L10", "=-ROUND(I10/23*3,2)"],
["L12", "=-ROUND(I12/23*3,2)"],
["L13", "=ROUND(I13/23*3,2)"],
["L15", "=ROUND(I15/23*3,2)"],
["L16", "=ROUND(I16/23*3,2)"],
["I25", "=SUM(I10-I12-I13-I14-I15-I16)"],
["I27", "=SUM(C6+I10-I13-I14-I15-I16-I17+I19-I20)"],
["I31", "=ROUND(SUM(I29-I27),2)"],
["L27", "=SUM(I18-I19)"],
["I33", "=SUM(B33:H33)"],
["I34", "=SUM(B34:H34)"],
["I35", "=SUM(B35:H35)"],
["I36", "=SUM(B36:H36)"],
["B20","=IF(B18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(B19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],
["C20","=IF(C18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(C19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],
["D20","=IF(D18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(D19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],
["E20","=IF(E18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(E19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],
["F20","=IF(F18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(F19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],
["G20","=IF(G18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(G19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],
["H20","=IF(H18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(H19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"]
]`
```

I can't figure out where the missing ] goes.

The formula in my sheet only seem to work with " not '. It enters text into the cell based on the IF conditions.

Comment: Please show enough of the script so that we can generate the errow.  We call that a [mcve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.setFormula() and received error missing ) argument list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429442/setformula-and-received-error-missing-argument-list)

Comment: Escape all intervening double quotes. Note the color here. They should be uniform.

Comment: Although I'm not sure `Enter Name`, for example, as another way, how about enclosing ` like ``["B20",`=IF(B18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(B19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))`]``?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike I tried that and get an illegal character error.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster I had a look at that post and I still get the error if I use /' instead of ". The formula doesn't work in my sheet unless I use " as it enters text into the cell based on the if conditions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, is V8 enabled? If it's not, please enable V8 at the script editor and test it again.

Comment: That let me save it, but does not retain the formula when the sheet resets. It also turns the IF(B18 black and the 49.99 green.

Comment: Try `["B20",'=IF(B18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(B19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))'],1`......

Comment: Are you sure you provided the code exactly as you have it in your script? Could you provide a copy of the script (free of sensitive information)?

Comment: @TheMaster thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

you're missing a comma at `["K14", "=I14"],`. That may what the error is really about, along with the comment about escaping the double-quotes ( `\"`)

Comment: Hi, I added the comma and I still get an error. The error specific refers to line 39, which is  ["B20","=IF(B18>49.99,"Enter Name",IF(B19>49.99,"Enter Name",""))"],

Comment: `"=IF(B18>49.99,\"Enter Name\",IF(B19>49.99,\"Enter Name\",\"\"))"` <---does this help? (my mind is having trouble working out this spreadsheet formula, ha)

Comment: I get the error Unterminated string literal with that one. Unless there is another formula I can use that enters text into cell B20 based on the value in B18 and B19 (separately)